# What do these three lines through the measure mean?

Tags: notation

The below image is from the Clarinet II part of Samuel Barber's Violin concerto. I don't have the faintest clue as to what these three lines could mean in this context. The notation is preceded by a volti subito, but I'm not sure what impact that has on this. Does anyone know what this could mean?

[image: Barber Violin Concerto, mm. 9–20, with three diagonal lines through the center of the staff line below]

Comment: That helps, but what I really meant is that it appears to be hand written, at least in part. What is the source of the image itself?

Comment: Here is a copy of the score: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qoggq4wip9lkp8t/Barber_2nd-Clarinet.pdf?dl=0

Comment: @Aaron Boosey and Hawkes (and other publishers, no doubt) published quite a bit of mid-20th-century music in photo-reproduced manuscript.  This was after photoreproduction became technologically feasible and before computer engraving existed or before it could produce satisfactory results -- between the 1940s and the 1980s, I would guess.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The three lines are the equivalent of scribbling out the bottom staff line. It's just attempting to make clear that there is no more music to be played on that page.

In the interest of overkill, here's an expanded image of the portion of the score involved.

[image: Score showing bottom of the page, to clarify the extra staff line]

Comment: …and the **VS** at the end of the previous stave means "turn the page quickly"- copyist is trying to be really clear.

Comment: VS stands for Volto Subito which indeed means turn immediately.

Comment: I'm going to add boxed text with an arrow marking "bottom of the page" to the next piece I write...

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS  And I would like to thank the copyist for making the page turn occur during an extended rest!  :-)

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS You can contact my agent about the copyright fee.